# Django: 'Settings' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

Depending on if I am in staging or production I either load settings.production or settings.staging.

Now I want to check if CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE is set, but I always receive `'Settings' object has no attribute 'CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE'`. This only happens in production, as my settings.staging is not loaded there. In .staging I wrote `CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE = True`

```
from django.conf import settings

def mixpanel_id(self):
    if settings.CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE:
        cross_subdomain_cookie = True
    else:
        cross_subdomain_cookie = False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`getattr(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr) and add a default value for that, for example:

```
from django.conf import settings

def mixpanel_id(self):
    if getattr(settings, 'CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE', False):
        cross_subdomain_cookie = True
    else:
        cross_subdomain_cookie = False
```

So here as default we set `False`. In case the `CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE` is missing, we will obtain `False`, otherwise `getattr(..)` will return the value of the attribute.

Note that an `if`-`else` that returns `True`/`False` can be simplified to:

```
def mixpanel_id(self):
    cross_subdomain_cookie  = bool(getattr(settings, 'CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE', False))
```

and in case the attribute is *always* a boolean, we can even write:

```
def mixpanel_id(self):
    cross_subdomain_cookie = getattr(settings, 'CROSS_SUBDOMAIN_COOKIE', False)
```

In case the default is `True`, or another value, you thus can replace the `False` by that value.

Comment: Perfect answer. Solved all problems. Thank you!